# kotlin clock & timer

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, clock

I have a timer and I want to connect the timer time to a clock to let the user see at what time the timer will stop.

For example the timer start at 12:28pm and will finish after 12 min at 12:40pm

How can I do this in Kotlin.

This the code

```
val timer = object : CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            var diff = millisUntilFinished
            val secondsInMilli: Long = 1000
            val minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60
            val elapsedMinutes = diff / minutesInMilli
            diff %= minutesInMilli

            var currentclock : TextClock
            var clockfinish : TextClock
            
           textview1.text = "$elapsedMinutes min"

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            textview1.text = "Your time is up"

        }
    }
    timer.start()
```

How can I connect the timer time to **clockfinish** .

Comment: Could you share a bit of code about what you have and where you're stuck? What are the types of values that you're using to represent the duration and clock?

Comment: If you know Java, write Java code and [convert it to Kotlin in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#convert) :P

Comment: Sure it's updated now with the code @Joffrey